# Logging message.author from one command and pulling it to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot that does tickets which are used as applications and I have most of it done except I want the bot when the `-close` command is used to log the ticket that was closed.

I've tried a few things such as calling a .then to send a message to the logging channel of the specific channel being deleted then calling another .then when it was deleted except it would still send the message saying `#deleted-channel`. I tried this in a few ways but I couldn't figure it out.

Another solution I tried was creating a variable in the `-apply` command that would log the name of the person that created the message but I realized that after many people used the command apply if I attempted to close one it would log the most recent applicant's name, not the application I was closing

-apply command

```
const reason = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
    var tAuthor = message.author.tag
    if (!message.guild.roles.exists("name", "[»] Helpers")) return message.channel.send(`Server does not have role set correctly., This error has been logged. \nPlease contact bot developer <@251557870603075586>`);
    if (message.guild.channels.exists("name", "t-staff-" + message.author.tag)) return message.reply(`You already have an application open.`);
    message.guild.createChannel(`t-staff-${message.author.tag}`, "text").then(c => {
        let role = message.guild.roles.find("name", `${config.role}`);
        let role2 = message.guild.roles.find("name", "@everyone");
        c.overwritePermissions(role, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            READ_MESSAGES: true
        });
        c.overwritePermissions(role2, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            READ_MESSAGES: false
        });
        c.overwritePermissions(message.author, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            READ_MESSAGES: true
        });
        c.setParent(message.guild.category.exists("name", "t-staff-"))
        message.reply(`:white_check_mark: Your application has been created, #${c.name}.`);
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0xCF40FA)
        .setTitle(`Staff Application`)
        .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>`)
        .addField(`Requirements`, `You must meet all the requirements:\n\n1. Professional attitude and grammar\n2. Working Microphone\n3. No severe punishments on the server. (Racial Slurs, DDos Threats, etc..)\n4. You must be over the age of 14`)
        .addBlankField()
        .addField(`Note:`, `Please check in announcements for open staff positions`)
        .addField(`Note:`, `Please paste the format with your answers`)
        .addField(`Note:`, `If your previous application was denied you must wait one week to sumbit a new one`)
        .addBlankField()
        .addField('Format', `\nWhat position are you applying for: \n\nMinecraft username: \n\nPrevious Minecraft usernames: \n\nWhat is your age: \n\nTimezone: \n\nAbility to record Minecraft video: \n\nHow much time do you have to contribute a week? \n\nWhat do you consider to be your biggest weaknesses?\n\nWhat's your dream job? \n\nHow do you deal with pressure or stressful situations? \n\nAny previous staff skills or experience? \n\nHave you ever been banned or punished for your actions on this server? If so, please include details. \n\nTell us about a time you made a mistake within the last year? How did you deal with it? What did you learn? \n\nAre you currently staff on any other servers? \n\nWhere did you hear about nodepvp? \n\nHave you made any previous applications, if so how many and what is the date of your last one? \n\nWhat would be your daily tasks for the rank you are applying for \n\nAnything else we should know? `)
        .addBlankField()
        .setTimestamp();
        c.send({ embed: embed });
        client.channels.get(`568210811009499136`).send(`:white_check_mark: !!!Ticket Created ${message.author} at **${current_date}**`);
```

-close command

```
if (!message.channel.name.startsWith(`ticket-`)) return message.channel.send(`You can't use the close command outside of a ticket channel.`);
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send(`${message.author} Do not have permission to close this application`);
        // Confirm delete - with timeout (Not command)
        message.channel.send(`Are you sure? Once confirmed, you cannot reverse this action!\nTo confirm, type \`/confirm\`. This will time out in 10 seconds and be cancelled.`)
            .then((m) => {
                message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content === '/confirm', {
                        max: 1,
                        time: 10000,
                        errors: ['time'],
                    })
                    .then((collected) => {
                        message.channel.delete();
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        m.edit('Ticket close timed out, the ticket was not closed.').then(m2 => {
                            m2.delete();
                        }, 3000);
                    });
            });
```

When I tried to log this by using a `.then` function in the close command right before

```
.then((collected) => {
                        message.channel.delete();
```

It still sends the message to the channel saying `#deleted-channel` even though I'm sending the command before the channel is deleted.

Comment: It might just be me but I have a bit of a tough time understanding your problem. So what happends is someone uses the `-apply` command which creates a new ticket channel. Then when a user uses the `-close` command in a ticket channel you want that channel AND the message with the corresponding `-apply` command to be deleted? Or do you want the original `-apply` message to retain the channel name even after it has been deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send a message with a channel mention, such as `#test`, it will stay as a clickable link to the `test` channel, as long as that channel exists. If you delete that channel, all links will seize and become a dull `#deleted-channel`.

One solution would be to log `Closed ${channel.name}`, then deleting the channel.
You cannot make it so it keeps the linked message (unless you make it so no one can see the *deleted* channel by denying read access to *closed* tickets for everyone except staff for logging purposes).